# RSelenium expected condition

Tags: r, selenium

In `RSelenium`, is it possible to do something similar to this `Selenium` python code, using `expected_conditions` to wait until a text is **not** present in an element?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
downloads = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/header/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
downloads.text #'Downloads'
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/header/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a"), 'Downloads'))
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example by providing a link

Comment: hello, it is done.

Comment: I am not familiar with python, but do you want to hover mouse over `Downloads`?

Comment: No, I want to wait until the text changes in a given element